# Accessing an instance variable within the `initialize` method

Tags: ruby, oop, object

Given this basic class in Ruby:

```
class TestClass
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

How do I then access the instance variable name directly from within the `initialize` method without creating a getter function? is this even possible? (i.e. using dot notation) or does the `initialize` method cease to exist once a class is instantiated, hence the need to define a getter method?

I think what I'm trying to ask is `initialize` a class or instance method?

Comment: `initialize` is a private instance method. After assigning the value of `name` to `@name` you can refer to `@name` within `initialize`. For example, `if @name == "Suzie" ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "getter method" is defined so that you can use the variable from outside the class:

```
class TestClass
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
# TestClass.new('Ben').name  # => 'Ben'
```

If you don't need to access it from outside the class, you can just use `@name`:

```
class TestClass
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet
    puts "Hello, %s" % @name
  end
end
# TestClass.new('Ben').greet # outputs: Hello, Ben
```

You can use the `@name` inside initialize:

```
class TestClass
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    puts "Name backwards: %s" % @name.reverse
  end
end
# TestClass.new('Ben') # outputs neB
```

Initialize is a special method, when you define `initialize` instance method, it is automatically marked `private`. The class method `new` calls it after creating an instance of your class.

Nothing stops you from calling private methods from inside the class:

```
class TestClass
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    puts "Name is now %s" % @name
  end

  def flip_name
    initialize(@name.reverse)
  end
end
# t = TestClass.new('Ben') # outputs "Name is now Ben"
# t.flip_name # outputs "Name is now neB"
# t.instance_variable_get(:@name) # => 'neB'
```

The `flip_name` method that calls `initialize` works just fine, but of course this is quite unconventional and almost never used, because it does not make much sense.

It's possible to call private methods from outside the class using `send`:

```
# t.send(:initialize, 'Bill') # outputs "Name is now Bill"
# t.instance_variable_get(:@name) # => 'Bill'
```

Without send, you get `NoMethodError`:

```
> t.initialize('Jack')
NoMethodError: private method `initialize' called for #<TestClass:0x00007fa2df8e4570>
```

Ruby 1.9 beta releases changed `send` to act like `public_send` does today, allowing access to only public methods and there was going to be `funccall` for calling private methods if you really want to, for unit testing purposes for example. I think it caused too much compatibility issues and the change was reverted.

So in conclusion, yes, you can call `initialize` again and it does not cease to exist, but it is almost never done because it makes very little sense. To access instance variables from inside the class, you use `@` notation like `@name`, to access them from outside of the class, you define a getter.

Comment: Thanks for your extremely thorough and brilliant answer Kimmo. Could I just ask for additional context around 'why' the `send` method is required/necessary to access a private instance method such as `initialize`? I know you receive a `NoMethodError` otherwise, but could you explain what `send` method does that allows you to access the `initialize` method from outside the class. Thanks.

Comment: Ruby 1.9 was going to make `send` act like `public_send` which only allows access to public methods, there was supposed to be `funccall` for calling private methods if you really want to (for unit testing purposes perhaps?). I don't know why it was left that way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way. But it's not a traditional one. It's more like querying the object to know

```
TestClass.new("foo").instance_variable_get(:@name)
=> "foo"
```

The `initialize` method does not "cease to exsist". It's executed, that's it. What your method do, in your case, is that the variable is set.

Comment: I think the OP is just looking for `@name`.

Comment: I'm not sure @CarySwoveland. Let's see what the OP says

Comment: Thanks @Ursus. Could you try to answer my other questions in your answer. Also, why is it not possible to use conventional dot notation such as `test = TestClass.new('Foo'); puts test.initialize;` like in the case of a normal getter method.

Comment: You can't call `initialize` directly. It's a special method. It's called when you call `new` on a class.

Comment: The `initialize` method doesn't even have a return value

Comment: @Ursus you can `return` from initialize, but the return value is not used for anything normally. `send(:initialize)` or calling it from inside the class will give the return value like any method.